# Help solving an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, with a teething baby my mind is creating a blank.

I have an equation, where I need to solve it to be P = ???

The equation is:

```
V = ((F + ((P/B) * G)) * A^M) + ((P/B) * H)
```

Thank you so much, my sleep deprived brain says thanks as well

Comment: Could you show us your work so far? :-)

Comment: Looks NP-hard to me.

Comment: My work so far is to simplify it down to that. It was originally a lot more complex. It is basically a Future Value calculation where by the person makes payments which are indexed by inflation and then makes a large drawdown pre-retirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$V = ((F + \frac{PG}{B}) * A^M) + \frac{HP}{B}$$
Solving it for $P$ means isolating $P$. So we want $P$ by itself. First we multiply both sides by $B$. $$BV = A^MBF+A^MPG+HP$$ $$BV = A^MBF+P(A^MG+H)$$ $$BV - A^MBF = P(A^MG+H)
$$ $$P = \frac{BV-A^MBF}{A^MG+H}$$

Comment: Thank you - brain was just mush by the time I had simplified it down

Answer (score 0):

$$V-FA^M=P\left(\frac{G}{B}\right)A^M + P\left(\frac{H}{B}\right)=P\left(\left(\frac{G}{B}\right)A^M + \left(\frac{H}{B}\right)\right)$$

$$P=\frac{V-FA^M}{\left(\frac{G}{B}\right)A^M + \left(\frac{H}{B}\right)}$$